FlutterWindow::MessageHandler code not woking in flutter plugin
I have tried to covert the below code as plugin but whenever we create a plugin using command
flutter create --template=plugin --platform=windows demo_plugin its missing the Win32_windows files and we are not able to create the
LRESULT
FlutterWindow::MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT const message,
                              WPARAM const wparam,
                              LPARAM const lparam) noexcept {

I want to detect the USB insertion and removal without this MessageHandler I wont be able to detect the USB as I get the events in WM_CREATE, WM_DEVICECHANGE, DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL inside MessageHandler.
(I am not C++ developer, struggling to do this)
if any one can give some insight on it would be helpful thanks in advance.
I have a normal flutter project where i have written the code for  MessageHandler similar to below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/78197668/8996167
Only change is in MessageHandler i have added WM_CREATE, WM_DEVICECHANGE, DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL filters for USB detection. and it works fine.
but
I want to create a plugin out of it as USB detection but the same code in plugin is not working getting errors WIN32_windows file not present, even if i manually add them its not working
UsbDetectPlugin::MessageHandler': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods

